# Get number of values in an array above a given value

Tags: php, arrays, count

So I have an array that contains an ID as the Key and created TIME as the Value, 
For example, my array looks like below,

```
$id_time_array = [
[21]=> 1540494319
[939]=> 1540494328
[2205]=> 1540494331 ];
```

And I want to get the number of ID's created within last 3 hours or so, is there a function in PHP for this or what would be the easiest way to get the count?

Comment: What @DontPanic said is correct. But, I have to ask, are these values coming from a database? If so, it would be much faster to use the query engine to do this filter.

Comment: @colefner I agree, and it could do the count faster as well.

Comment: @colefner a serialized array is coming from DB

Comment: Well, the db probably won't help much in that case.

Comment: Oh, oh yeah, then you would have to handle the counting/filtering in the app layer . There are ways to search serialized data with mysql, but it's likely not any more efficient than doing it with PHP. http://blastar.biz/2013/11/28/how-to-use-mysql-to-search-in-php-serialized-fields/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've established the cutoff timestamp

```
$cutoff = strtotime('3 hours ago');
```

You can filter the array to items greater than the cutoff value and count the result of that.

```
$result = count(array_filter($array, function($timestamp) use ($cutoff) {
    return $timestamp > $cutoff;
}));
```

If you only need the count, you don't need to do anything with the ID.

---

The second argument to `array_filter` is an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

```
function($timestamp) use ($cutoff) {  return $timestamp > $cutoff; }
```

The `use` statement introduces the `$cutoff` variable into the [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) of the anonymous function. Otherwise, the function would not have access to that variable. You can read about it in more detail in the PHP documentation I linked.

[example at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/sMdot)

Comment: @DontPanic could you please explain a bit on what does " function($timestamp) use ($cutoff)" do?

Comment: @DaBeginer I added some explanation of that to the answer.